# mv command lost all files. Can find files by locate function but not in file manager

Tags: linux, command-line, mv

I was trying to move all Video files(not Directory) from withing my Downloads folder to the Videos folder...

I assumed I was safe as in my mind move is not delete. I may be learning that this is the case the hard way.

I tried the following command:

```
find /home/billy/Downloads -type f -iname "*.mkv" -o -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.avi" | xargs /bin/rm -f | xargs -I list mv list /home/billy/Videos/
```

It looked like it worked as the video files were gone from the sub directories. But they didn't land in the Video Directory at all. In fact, I can't find them anywhere. I try a locate *.mkv and it finds my files and says they are right where they were. However, the files aren't there when I navigate to the containing folders...

Are the files recoverable?

Does anyone know where my silly command may have put them?

Why can locate find them but they aren't there?

Comment: Just saw this about the locate function. locate uses a database called locatedb. It's normally updated by system cron jobs. If the DB hasn't been updated, it'll show non-existent or new files/directories. you can force an update with the updatedb command. See this link among others.

Comment: So I guess I just deleted all my movies :'(

Comment: What did you expect from the `/bin/rm -f` command?!

Comment: you will have to attempt to undelete them with data recovery tools.

Comment: Shut down your system as fast as possible and get some recovery tool, maybe you can restore some of them. Don't write anything further to this hard disk / partition as it will reduce the chance of successfully recovering your files.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't move your files. You removed them. The following bit of your command does this:

```
xargs /bin/rm -f
```

As pointed out in the comments, the locate command can find them because it is using an outdated database. It's time to restore from backup.

Comment: I was messing around with the recomendations on this page: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-find-move-all-mp3-file.html

Comment: This page doesn't contain a call to `rm`.

Comment: @scai I copied the command from the question itself. I'm not sure why you can't see it, but it's definitely there. The full command is: find /home/billy/Downloads -type f -iname "*.mkv" -o -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.avi" | xargs /bin/rm -f | xargs -I list mv list /home/billy/Videos/

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton I wanted to refer to the page mentioned by BillyLeo, sorry for the confusion :)